# spring social Sign-in using facebook

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-social

I did the registration flow successfully and user profile got registered and got created a record in userconnection table.

I am using Spring-social with Spring security followed the steps mentioned in this [blog](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/adding-social-sign-in-to-a-spring-mvc-web-application-registration-and-login/)

Now my issue is on the journey 2 that means the user registered already using facebook, and need to login using facebook. I am able to set the post login url in this way

```
SpringSocialConfigurer sc = new SpringSocialConfigurer();
    sc.postLoginUrl("/account/social");
```

And added this to the security filter chain.

So the call coming in this method, but the connection is always null. Actually I want to get the user ID and username of the logged in user

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/account/social", method = { RequestMethod.GET})
public void resendUsl(HttpServletRequest request,WebRequest request1, HttpServletResponse response,Model model) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("here");
    Connection<?> connection = ProviderSignInUtils.getConnection(request1);
```

I have tried create a class `SimpleSignInAdaptor` but the call is not coming here at all.

```
public class SimpleSignInAdaptor implements SignInAdapter {
```

How can I get the user details after login success?

thanks for the help

**UPDATE**Resolved this way, but this have the issue if the user registered with facebook and twitter account and trying to login using one either one of them. it always getting the facebook connection   Got connection object via connection repository 
`@Inject private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/social", method = { RequestMethod.GET})
public void resendUsl(HttpServletRequest request,WebRequest request1, HttpServletResponse response,Model model) throws IOException {

    Connection<Facebook> connection = connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you out : [Spring Social Project](https://github.com/arpitaggarwal/Spring-Social)

Comment: I am using it with spring security.

Comment: Just add the Spring Security layer over it :)

Comment: @Arpit I'm using your project and works great! but how can I use this mechanism to create a new user and automatically authenticate him in my spring mvc app? thanks

Comment: @rmpt: Add a layer of Spring Security on top of it with users dynamically created. Reference : https://github.com/arpitaggarwal/spring-app